# How can I extract an int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, web-scraping, integer

I'm new on stack overflow, I'm writing a script in python and I've got a doubt that I can resolve, I need to create a variable with the price of the product, by now I've collected decimal price in €, thanks to web scraping.

```
import bs4, requests
 
link = "https://hookpod.shop/products/hookpod-screw-adapter"
 
response = requests.get(link)
response.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeatifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parster')
span_price = soup.find('span', class_='product__price')
```

what output gives to me is:

`<span class="product__price" data-product-price=""> €10.00 </span>`

I need to get the amount (€10.00) and transform it in a `int`, is there anybody who can help me with, I really need it

Comment: `span_price = int(span_price.text.replace('€', ''))`

Answer (score 1):

converting span_price text to int will solve it.

something like:

```py
var int_span_price = int(span_price.text.replace('€', ''))
```

Comment: you need to first convert to `float` tho, otherwise you will get an error

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int()` see above comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The find method return a Tag object and you can access to its string via the `text` attribute. Then you should remove the empty space around it with `strip`, and the money-symbol, with a slice for example. The cast to `float` and finally with `int`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span class="product__price" data-product-price=""> €10.00 </span>'

span_price = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml') # you can change parser

span_price_value = int(float(span_price.text.strip()[1:]))

print(span_price_value)
```

Remark:

1. I used another parser bit make no difference just be sure to change it if you haven't install it (`lxml`)
2. if don't use `strip` then you should be careful with the slice of the string, not more at 1

Answer (score 0):

use Beautiful Soup's [tag](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) system to lock on that data and soup.getText() to pull it out. You could also parse the results of the soup.find method you did there

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for answering! Could you provide a more complete example based on the original question? It'll make things clearer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use https://pypi.org/project/price-parser/

To install it run `pip install price-parser`

```py
>>> from price_parser import Price
>>> price = Price.fromstring("22,90 €")
>>> price
Price(amount=Decimal('22.90'), currency='€')
>>> price.amount       # numeric price amount
Decimal('22.90')
>>> price.currency     # currency symbol, as appears in the string
'€'
>>> price.amount_text  # price amount, as appears in the string
'22,90'
>>> price.amount_float # price amount as float, not Decimal
22.9
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a couple of typos so I am writing the full code. Use regex to get the  digits out of the Euro prices you got already.

```
import bs4, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://hookpod.shop/products/hookpod-screw-adapter"

response = requests.get(link)
response.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
span_price = soup.find('span', class_='product__price')

import re
result = re.search(r'\d+', span_price.text)
result_int = int(result.group())
result_int
```

Comment: I see only your code gives the correct result: <class 'int'>
10

Comment: The correct captured value from the url is €10,00  not €10.00 as shown in the question. So converting to float does not work.

Comment: The capture value that  showing  from the url   is creating  the exception.